# react hook form , mapping an array on radio button not getting value in first click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, radio-button, react-hook-form

I am using react hook form for my form validation , i am using an array and mapping in radio button , but after selecting one radio value , when i click submit , i am not getting the value , if i click after that i get the value,

```
{Co.map((item, index) => (
          <label key={index} htmlFor={`int${index}`}>
            <input
              type="radio"
              id={`int${index}`}
              {...register('interestedTypes', {
                required: true,
              })}
              value={item.Value}
            />
            <h3
              className="aLMS__chooseButton"
              onClick={() => handlePropertyForClick(index)}
            >
              <img src={item.restIcon} alt="" />
              {item.name}
            </h3>
          </label>
        ))}
```

co=["1","2","3"]

Comment: Please reduce your code to the minimal reproduction of the problem and use `code snippet`, so that we can run it and see the problem.